# Problems in drawing a rectangle inside a rectangle in xml android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to draw a transparent rectangle inside another transparent rectangle but I am facing some issues. But here is the problem - In my current output I want my back rectangle to be transparent rather than having that white color in the body. How do I do that.
[XML picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeWxP.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Larger blue circle in back -->
    <item
        android:width="25dp"
        android:height="25dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="15px"
                android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="8dp"
        android:bottom="35dp"
        android:top="35dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="8dp"
        android:bottom="35dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:top="35dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:height="8dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:left="35dp"
        android:right="35dp"
        android:top="-1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:height="8dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:left="35dp"
        android:right="35dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: a normal shape drawable can be used to do that. couldn't it ?

Comment: Isn't this a re-post of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828385/problems-with-drawing-a-rectangle-within-a-rectangle-in-a-drawable)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with drawing a rectangle within a rectangle in a drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828385/problems-with-drawing-a-rectangle-within-a-rectangle-in-a-drawable)

Answer (score -1):

You draw a transparent rectangle on the white rectangle. In fact, the transparent rectangle was drawn successfully. But it is transparent so you still see the white rectangle. You should redraw all the shapes and bitmap.